# Adding a text file into a list and then into a Two Dimensional array

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a text file that has the following in it: (Without quotation marks and "Empty Space")

- ##############
- # Empty Space#
- # Empty Space#
- # Empty Space#
- # Empty Space#
- ##############

I want to add this whole file row by row into a list:

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream(@"FilePath",FileMode.Open);
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS);
List<string> MapLine = new List<string>();

foreach (var s in SR.ReadLine())
{
    MapLine.Add(s.ToString());                   
}

foreach (var x in MapLine)
{
    Console.Write(x);
}
```

Here comes my problem: I want to add this into a Two dimensional array. I tried:

```
string[,] TwoDimentionalArray = new string[100, 100];

for (int i = 0; i < MapLine.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MapLine.Count; j++)
    {
        TwoDimentionalArray[j, i] = MapLine[j].Split('\n').ToString();
    }
}
```

I am still new to C# so please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to end up with? Seems like your code is iterating far too many times. Post some examples of the result you want to see.

Comment: why do you need to dimensions ? can u just use each line as a string and contain it all in a single list ?

Comment: hi all i would like just to display the text file's data in a two dimensional array and display the array

Comment: You're trying to add `List<string>` into `string[,]`? What should be the elements in `string[,]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
        // File.ReadAllLines method serves exactly the purpose you need
        List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Data.txt").ToList();

        // lines.Max(line => line.Length) is used to find out the length of the longest line read from the file
        string[,] twoDim = new string[lines.Count, lines.Max(line => line.Length)];

        for(int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lines.Count; lineIndex++)
            for(int charIndex = 0; charIndex < lines[lineIndex].Length; charIndex++)
                twoDim[lineIndex,charIndex] = lines[lineIndex][charIndex].ToString();

        for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lines.Count; lineIndex++)
        {
            for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < lines[lineIndex].Length; charIndex++)
                Console.Write(twoDim[lineIndex, charIndex]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

This is going to save each character of the file content into it's own position in a 2-dimensional array. For that purpose `char[,]` might have also been used.

Comment: BOOM!!!!!!! OMG thank you so much that worked perfectly!!!!!  i am so great full thank you so much!!!!!! :)

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help:) If you find this answer most helpful you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are going through all the lines of your file, and for every line of your file, you go through all the lines of your file again, to split them on `\n` which is already done by you putting them in `MapLine`.

If you want every single char of a line array'd, and that in an array again, it should approximately look like this:

```
string[,] TwoDimentionalArray = new string[100, 100];

for (int i = 0; i < MapLine.Count; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < MapLine[i].length(); j++)
     {
          TwoDimentionalArray[i, j] = MapLine[i].SubString(j,j);
     }
}
```

I did this without testing so it might be faulty. The point is you need to iterate through each line first, then through each letter in that line. From there, you can use [`SubString`.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)

Also, I hope I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: the for loop works but it doe'tn add anything into the array. (Sorry guys i'm still very new to C#) :(